# Recursos en android densidad de pixeles, xxdpi, xdpi, hdpi, mdpi, ldpi

Tags: android, android-layout

Me encuentro que imágenes estáticas incluidas dentro de las apps, con aspect ratio 16:9 en tabletas se visualizan pinceladas cual es la manera de generar adecuadamente los recursos por cada densidad de pixeles `ldpi,mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi`

Entiendo que la resolución normal la que normalmente se ve en un monitor de PC es la `mdpi` y escalo la imagen dependiendo de la base `1024x576` con la siguiente [calculadora](https://pixplicity.com/dp-px-converter/)

con el siguiente resultado:

```
ldpi    = 768.00px
mdpi    = 1024.00px
tvdpi   = 1363.20px
hdpi    = 1536.00px
xhdpi   = 2048.00px
xxhdpi  = 3072.00px
xxxhdpi = 4096.00px
```

La imagen fuente tiene más que `5000px`,  digamos la disminuyo hacia 4096px para crear el xxhdpi, después a 3072px para el xxhdpi...

Pero aun así en una tableta [Asus TF101 sus especificaciones](http://www.gsmarena.com/asus_transformer_tf101-3936.php) se visualiza pixelado.

A parte de eso, tengo más cuestiones:

- Android studio solo tiene generador para iconos y vectores.
  ¿Que herramientas utilizáis para rendimensionar las imágenes automaticamente?

  la página [AndroidAssetStudio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/) no funciona con imágenes grandes
- Para ser más óptimo con el tamaño final del apk, Si solo se pone la imagen correspondiente en `drawable/xxxhdpi` es necesario ponerla en todas las otras o Android la re-dimensiona automáticamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que ya entiendo más o menos como se debe realizar, el programa de diseño que utilizo `fireworks` me deja escoger los dpi lo normal está en `72dpi` para impresión en pantalla PC.

Leyendo más sobre dpi y las constantes de [DisplayMetrics](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) veo que `DENSITY_DEFAULT=160`.

Creo una imagen en blanco con `160dpi` y asigno a`1024x756px` una vez creada, ren-dimensiono pero usando modificador `dpi` le asigno un nuevo valor de `640` que es la de `xxxhdpi` y me crea una imagen de `4681x2633` aquí meto la imagen fuente.

Y para todas las demás voy siguiendo esa tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora se me visualiza la imagen sin contorno escalado.

Con la herramienta [resize-9-patch](https://github.com/redwarp/9-Patch-Resizer/releases) se puede crear los recursos para cada pantalla.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que hacer la imagen pensando en una pantalla de 160x160 y luego escalarlas para cada densidad de pantalla.

En esta página puedes pasarle la imagen original y te genera automáticamente todas la imágenes escaladas y muchos otros recursos, ya funciona con cualquier imagen.
[Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html)

Y si quieres entender un poco mejor como funciona esto mírate este artículo corto que explica todo lo que tienes que saber al respecto.
[¿Qué son y para qué sirven los DP en Android?](https://tyris-software.com/que-son-y-para-que-sirven-los-dp-en-android/)

Espero que te ayude